# Driver specification for hyperref and graphicx

Tags: graphics, hyperref

When using `hyperref` and compiling via `pdflatex` or `dvips`, I do not need to specify the driver with `\usepackage{hyperref}`. However when compiling via `dvipdfm` this fails and I have to specify the driver using `\usepackage[dvipdfm]{hyperref}`. A similar situation occurs with the use of `graphicx`.

Why is that so? Is there a way to fix the `hyperref` or `graphicx` packages so that `dvipdfm` need not be manually specified each time?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A short answer is 'no, you always need to specify `dvipdfm` as a driver option'. To explain why, you need to remember that TeX does not handle things like colour, hyperlinks or including graphics directly. Instead, these are left to the driver to sort out. Each driver has its own way of doing things, and so the instructions needed for `dvips` are different from those for `dvipdfm` (or other drivers). These instructions are called 'specials' as they are included in a TeX file using the `\special` primitive. Things are a bit different when using pdfLaTeX as there are a whole family of PDF-specific primitives which do the same job. I'll just call all of these 'specials' in the following.

So why can `hyperref` and `graphicx` detect pdfLaTeX *versus* `dvips` but not `dvips` *versus* `dvipdfm`? At the (La)TeX level, it is possible to see that direct PDF output is being used, as the primitive `\pdfoutput` will be set to `1`. So the code which determines which specials to use can check this value and make a simple decision: if it is `1`, use the specials for direct PDF creation. On the other hand, if the value is `0` then there are more possibilities. The two major ones are, as you say, `dvips` and `dvipdfm`. There is no way to tell which of these will be used from within the LaTeX file, and they need different specials. So a decision was made that `dvips` would be assumed *unless* the user says otherwise. This is why you need to explicitly say `dvipdfm` as an option: once it is set then both `graphicx` and `hyperref` should pick up the setting.